# Trying to create dynamic widget area using post ID

Tags: widgets, sidebar

In `functions.php` I added this code.

```
function page_widget_init( $post_id = 0 ) { {
    register_sidebar( array(
        'name' => __( 'Page Widgets', 'seven_theme' ),
        'id' => 'page-widgets-' . $post_id,
        'description' => __( 'To display Layers Widgets in front page, before your posts, after header.', 'seven_theme' ),
    ) );    
}
add_action( 'widgets_init', 'page_widget_init', 100 );
```

First how to get post id in `functions.php register_sidebar **$post_id**`

Now going to page template which i created using page.php, called **Blog Template**

Call this widget in this page.

```
dynamic_sidebar( 'page-widgets-' . $post->ID );
```

My idea is to create unique widget content using post ID.

Comment: Hi, anyone thinking about this widget type?

Answer (score 0):

In your code you are trying to register a different sidebar for every post. Now, that would be possible (though with slightly different code), but it would mean that if you have, say, a hundred posts, you would have hundred widget areas in your admin, all of which you would have to fill with different widgets that have their own content.

I don't know what exactly you are trying to achieve, but if you want to pull information from specific posts in a sidebar, you probably want to [build a widget](https://codex.wordpress.org/Widgets_API). You can still have unique information on every page, but not a cluttered widget dashboard.

I can think of more complicated setups, but you would have to provide more detail on what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: Yes that is right i am trying to do the same, but not for post, adding it to pages. Looking for dynamic widget area with unique content in each pages.

Comment: @inkcolor That would mean you need a different sidebar for pages only. Or a widget that only displays content on a page.

Comment: Yes that would be for pages only. And i will call it in pages.php or pages templates.